# show the key name of associated array in drop down list

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $month=array("January"=>"01","February"=>"02","March"=>"03","April"=>"04",
                 "May"=>"05","June"=>"06","July"=>"07","August"=>"08","September"=>"09",
                "October"=>"10","November"=>"11","December"=>"12");


    echo"<select name='month'>";
    echo"<option>-select-</option>";
    for($i=0;$i<12;$i++)
    {

        echo "<option>".$month[$i]."</option>"."<br />";
    }
    echo"</select>";

      ?>
```

i want to display the name January,February.. in drop down option and also want their value in another variable.

Comment: Then use `foreach` unstead of `for`

Answer (score 0):

```
$month=array("January"=>"01","February"=>"02","March"=>"03","April"=>"04",
                 "May"=>"05","June"=>"06","July"=>"07","August"=>"08","September"=>"09",
                "October"=>"10","November"=>"11","December"=>"12");

echo"<select name='month'>";
echo"<option>-select-</option>";

foreach($month as $key=>$value){

  echo "<option value='". $value ."'>".$key."</option>"."<br />";
}


 echo"</select>";
```

$value will give its values.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `foreach` in this case:

```
<?php
$month=array("January"=>"01","February"=>"02","March"=>"03","April"=>"04","May"=>"05","June"=>"06","July"=>"07","August"=>"08","September"=>"09","October"=>"10","November"=>"11","December"=>"12");
?>
<select name="month">
<?php foreach($month as $k => $v) {
    echo "<option value='" . $v . "'>" . $k . "</option>";
} ?>
</select>
```

We're storing the associative array's key and value in separate variables and echoing them out accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using foreach loop.

```
foreach ($month as $name => $value) {
        echo "<option>".$name."</option>"."<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach and print the key values

```
   <?php

    $month=array("January"=>"01","February"=>"02","March"=>"03","April"=>"04",
                     "May"=>"05","June"=>"06","July"=>"07","August"=>"08","September"=>"09",
                    "October"=>"10","November"=>"11","December"=>"12");

                    foreach($month as $key=>$value){
                      echo "<option>".$key."</option>"."<br />";
                    }
     ?>
```